# Реализация аутентификации ASP.NET Core WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Вопрос такой, нужно реализовать аутентификацию с помощью JWT.Схема базы данных выглядит так:
[[image: Ctvf]

Т.е. у меня 3 вида пользователей, это админ, тренер, клиент. И я вот думаю, мне реализовать аутентификацию в контроллерах этих моделей и там давать роли пользователям, или же создать один контроллер аутентификации и там уже всех аутентифицировать. Но если создавать общий, то я не знаю как правильно это реализовать. Помогите с данным вопросом.

Comment: Используйте встроенную в ASP.NET аутентификацию, там уже есть возможность настройки по ролям.  Вот в  этом [видео](https://youtu.be/FFaE42OEKfg?si=8TJUXg-6xSXHEvxc), показан пример настройки аутентификации для проектов с WEB API и проектов ASP.NET MVC на .NET 7

Comment: @AndreiBrizhak да нет, я это понял. Имеется ввиду, как лучше реализовать? В одном контроллере все проверять, или в разных. Можете прям ссылочку на видео оставить, а то из за проблем с безопасностью не могу открыть.

Comment: Ок, если коротко ответить на вопрос, то я бы создавал отдельный контроллер для управления пользователями,  вот в этом [плейлисте](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLePGPxR0FDm9oltBczmL_0S3zK5GbJ1rX) есть кое что об этом - https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLePGPxR0FDm9oltBczmL_0S3zK5GbJ1rX    Попробую также дать полный ответ,  как я это понимаю с тремя вариантами решения.

Comment: @AndreiBrizhak спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможны четыре варианта решения, если не выходить за рамки идентификации в .NET, и  в зависимости от того, что вам больше нравится, а также какой тип приложения будет использовать ваше API, со встроенной идентификацией.

Вариант первый.

- Создаете отдельный контроллер с управлением пользователями и их ролями на уровне API;
- Настраиваете в API, хранение информации о пользователях в базе данных;
- Создаете в API, методы для регистрации нового пользователя или авторизации, существующего пользователя.
- В методе авторизации пользователя, с помощью секретного ключа, генерируете JWT токены;
- Передаете такой токен в ответе на авторизацию, только тому пользователю который переслал в сообщении логин и пароль, а точнее не пароль, а его хеш,
  при этом авторизация должна быть успешно пройдена.
- Далее в веб приложении, если оно написано на ASP.NET, создается отдельный контроллер для управления пользователями, где в представлениях вводятся данные для авторизации или регистрации, и такие данные передаются в запросах к API. Именно этот способ описывается в [плейлисте](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLePGPxR0FDm9oltBczmL_0S3zK5GbJ1rX), указанном в моем комментарии выше.
- Также нужно будет настроить хранение и передачу такого токена, для авторизованных запросов, от веб приложения к API, хранение токена можно настроить в сессиях.

Вариант второй.
Сделать все этапы настройки из первого варианта, но использовать при этом на уровне API,  автоматическую генерацию таблиц и другой логики с помощью библиотеки Identity,  в веб приложении также нужно будет настроить отдельный контроллер, и передавать в параметрах запросов на авторизацию или идентификацию, данные по требованиям библиотеки Identity.

Вариант третий.
Использование отдельного сервера идентификации Duende IdentityServer, это платное ПО, если ваша организация зарабатывает более миллиона баксов в год.
В этом варианте управление пользователя и их ролями осуществляется на уровне этого самого сервера идентификации.
Веб приложение, через свой контроллер теперь обращается к серверу идентификации, для регистрации нового пользователя или для авторизации
пользователей. При успешной авторизации веб приложение получает Identity Token для пользователя.
Затем на каждый запрос к ресурсам API, авторизованные запросы от веб приложения сначала получают, токены доступа (Access Token ) из сервера идентификации,
после чего, такого токена доступа, этот токен передается вместе с запросом к ресурсам API, получив такой запрос с токеном доступа, API, запрашивает подтверждение валидности этого токена на сервере идентификации. Получив подтверждение, API предоставляет данные для запроса веб приложению.
Такой вариант рассмотрен в [плейлисте](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLePGPxR0FDm8QaxE2BOFg6Kl3dt7rlKpl&si=L83ih72yuOPL_mDK)

Вариант четвертый.
Microsoft предложила замену платному Duende Identity Server,
но этот вопрос я еще не изучил, и возможно ошибаюсь.